# Creating a "presentable"/filtered twitter profile widget

Tags: javascript, twitter, api

I would like to include a subset of tweets I make on my professional web development site.

Now, twitter provides two applicable widgets:
a profile widget and a search widget

Unfortunately, the profile widget shows everything I tweet (including off-topic tweets that I don't want shown on my site).

On the other hand, the search widget generally only shows tweets that I have made in the last 24 hours, and apparently doesn't search back very far.

Here's an example of the search widget in action on my site: http://royronalds.com/log.html
(showing only one match of what should be many, because that's the only recent match).

And here are the widgets: http://twitter.com/widgets

Is there any way to create a topic-filtered widget, to show only on-topic tweets?

Comment: The twitter widgets have improved significantly since September 2010. They accomplish most of what you want, or rather there are many more choices now, see https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets

Comment: Pretty much identical to what it was, actually.

Comment: There's the Favorites widget which wasn't available before. That will get you past the 1-3 day time window constraint. You would be limited to only those tweets you starred, but that way you'd have total control over what was displayed on a professional website. Last idea: Try the advanced search and operators when you configure the profile widget: https://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced

Comment: That's true, but would result in a really static effect and I'd have to favorite my own posts all the time.  What I was doing was essentially having a filtered search where I put in a lot of topic keywords (e.g. coding, html, html5, webdesign, etc), so when I posted on those they'd show up.  But the small day limit meant usually nothing with those keywords showed up, left a blank app.  So it may be that the only solution is self-storage, unfortunately.  Or some third-party app that does the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RSS feed from Twitter, store the entries in your database (to get past the 24/72 hour limit) and use a #hashtag or similar which you can check for to see if should be published.

How often you check the feed, how purge database entries and how many #hashtags you use is up to you and the amount of time you have.

Comment: Twitter apparently dropped support for RSS feeds back in March 2013 unfortunately.